# Memory error in Rails console on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, out-of-memory, rails-console

I logged into our production instance on AWS, and tried to go into Rails console:

```
bundle exec rails c production
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
There was an error while trying to load the gem 'mini_magick' (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: Cannot allocate memory - animate
```

When I run free I see there's no swap:

```
free
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       7659512    7515728     143784        408       1724      45604
-/+ buffers/cache:    7468400     191112
Swap:            0          0          0

df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             3824796       12   3824784   1% /dev
tmpfs             765952      376    765576   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      15341728 11289944   3323732  78% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             3829756        0   3829756   0% /run/shm
none              102400        0    102400   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdf       10190136  6750744   2898720  70% /mnt
```

Not sure what's causing this or how to resolve it. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can increase EC2 instance memory or add swap memory to EC2.

```
  grep Mem /proc/meminfo
  grep Swap /proc/meminfo
  free
  uname -a
  # Set swap file to /swapfile1 
  sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile1 bs=1M count=512
  grep Swap /proc/meminfo

  ll /swapfile1
  sudo chmod 600 /swapfile1
  mkswap /swapfile1
  ll /swapfile1
  sudo mkswap /swapfile1
  swapon -s
  free
  sudo swapon /swapfile1
  free
  grep Swap /proc/meminfo
```